# VueJs - avoid useless v-for iteration

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for, vue-directives

**Hello,**
I noticed that when data is render like this:

```
<div v-for="post in posts">
  <p> {{post.content}} </p>
</div>
```

---

```
<pre>
data () {
    return {
      posts: [{...},{...}]
    }
  }
</pre>
```

and when I update posts array like this :

```
<pre>
methods: {
    addPost: function (post){
      this.posts.unshift(post);
    }
  }
</pre>
```

VueJs parse all data in posts, so loaded data is reloaded again, any idea ?

**Update**

---

```html
<template>
          <div v-for="post in postsArray" :key="post._id.$id">
            <p> {{post.content}} </p>
            <time>{{post.created_at}}</time>
            {{log('hey')}}
          </div>

</template>

<script>
import '...'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      posts: [{...}, {...}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addPost: function (post){
      // display max 10 posts
      if (this.posts.length >= 10)
      {
        this.posts.splice(9, 1)
      }
      this.posts.unshift(post);
    },
    log: function (log) {
      console.log(log);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    postsArray: function () {
      return this.posts.map(element => {
        let post;
        post = element;
        post.created_at = new Date(element.created_at.sec).toLocaleDateString();
        return post;
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

If I add a post, log function is call 10 times on first load and 20 times for 10 posts on update.
If it's because of log function, there is another way to test v-for iteration ? In fact, I want to verify that v-for iterate only once if I add post in posts.

Comment: Useful source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6342

Answer (score 0):

Whole list will be re-rendered because Vue have no clue how to detect which object was removed, because there is no meta-information for the post identity.

You need to specify "key" attribute, which explicitly defines id<->data binding.

```html
<div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
  <p> {{post.content}} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I try it and if I put a log function in v-for loop I have useless iteration, maybe because method log is in v-for loop ?

Comment: @cisco_bro You should show how you "put a log function in v-for loop". I assume your question is not about re-rendering at all and you do something like `v-if(item) :load='someLoggingFunction(item)'` inside `v-for`. And yes, if you do so, you get a log entry for each element whenever the array changes. I'm not sure if there's any way to avoid this.

Comment: @mayakwd yes in fact I want to verify the iterate number, but put a log method in template does not seem to be the right solution

Answer (score 0):

Vue does not understand what was the change in your list, so it renders the component again. You need to add an identifier in your loop.

```
<div v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

The `key` attribute is used to maintain the state. For more details about the `key` attribute, read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key)

Comment: But I don't understand, if I put a log method in v-for loop, logs are always equals to the length, I don't have one log

Comment: @cisco_bro Maybe you could post some code that you've tried, so we can help you.